# SwiftUI - UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath never called in UIViewRepresentable custom picker view

Tags: uitableview, swiftui

I'm trying to use `UIViewRepresentable` to incorporate this [picker view](https://github.com/filipealva/PickerView/blob/master/Pod/Classes/PickerView.swift) from this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/filipealva/PickerView) into my SwiftUI project.

I created a test project to illustrate the issue I'm having. Below is the code necessary to build the project (excluding `PickerView`, which I'm pulling from [here](https://github.com/filipealva/PickerView/blob/master/Pod/Classes/PickerView.swift)).

## Model

```swift
struct Fruit {
    let name: String
    let isInStock: Bool

    static let apple = Fruit(name: "apple", isInStock: true)
    static let orange = Fruit(name: "orange", isInStock: true)
    static let banana = Fruit(name: "banana", isInStock: true)
    static let raspberry = Fruit(name: "raspberry", isInStock: false)
    static let blueberry = Fruit(name: "blueberry", isInStock: false)
    static let lemon = Fruit(name: "lemon", isInStock: true)
    static let lime = Fruit(name: "lime", isInStock: false)
}
```

## ContentView

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fruits: [Fruit] = [.apple, .orange, .banana, .raspberry, .blueberry, .lemon, .lime]
    @State private var selectedFruit: Fruit = .apple

    var body: some View {
        FruitPicker(fruits: self.$fruits, selectedFruit: self.$selectedFruit)
    }
}
```

## FruitPicker

```swift
struct FruitPicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var fruits: [Fruit]
    @Binding var selectedFruit: Fruit

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PickerViewDelegate, PickerViewDataSource {
        @Binding var fruits: [Fruit]
        @Binding var selectedFruit: Fruit

        init(fruits: Binding<[Fruit]>, selectedFruit: Binding<Fruit>) {
            self._fruits = fruits
            self._selectedFruit = selectedFruit
        }

        func pickerViewNumberOfRows(_ pickerView: PickerView) -> Int {
            return self.fruits.count
        }

        func pickerViewHeightForRows(_ pickerView: PickerView) -> CGFloat {
            return 50
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: PickerView, titleForRow row: Int) -> String {
            return self.fruits[row].name
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: PickerView, didSelectRow row: Int) {
            self.selectedFruit = self.fruits[row]
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> FruitPicker.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(fruits: self.$fruits, selectedFruit: self.$selectedFruit)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FruitPicker>) -> PickerView {
        let pickerView = PickerView()

        pickerView.delegate = context.coordinator
        pickerView.dataSource = context.coordinator

        return pickerView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ pickerView: PickerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FruitPicker>) {

    }
}
```

`PickerView` uses `UITableView` to mimic the functionality of `UIPickerView` but with a flat appearance.

When I run the project, the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods in `PickerView.swift` for `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` are both called, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not.

I first tried selecting "Debug View Hierarchy" from the debugging tab, but Xcode crashes every time I do this. So then I set background colors to see if the picker view was appearing on screen at all, and it wasn't, so I put breakpoints inside `makeUIView` and `updateUIView` to check `PickerView`'s frame. In both cases, it came back as zero. I tried setting the frame for the picker view in `makeUIView`, but nothing changed - `cellForRowAtIndexPath` simply never gets called.

Does anyone have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong or what exactly is causing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to never be called?

Comment: Hello! Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue : (

Comment: Hello, Did you ever figure this out? I am having similar issue. Other delegates and datasource methods called but not cellForRow

Comment: Apologies for the super late reply. No, I never figured it out and ultimately reverted the entire view back to UIKit